# Sharepoint Online search.asmx : limit scope

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I'm trying to make a search request on the "/_vti_bin/search.asmx" page in Sharepoint Online.

I use the QueryEx method to post the request.

Here is the request:

```
        var xmlQuery = "<QueryPacket xmlns=\"urn:Microsoft.Search.Query\">";
        xmlQuery += "<Query>";
        xmlQuery += "<SupportedFormats><Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format></SupportedFormats>";
        xmlQuery += "<Context><QueryText type=\"STRING\" >" + keyword + "</QueryText></Context>";
        xmlQuery += "<SortByProperties><SortByProperty name=\"Rank\" direction=\"Descending\" order=\"1\"/></SortByProperties>";
        xmlQuery += "<Properties>";
        xmlQuery += "<Property name=\"SiteTitle\"/>";
        xmlQuery += "<Property name=\"Title\"/>";
        xmlQuery += "<Property name=\"Path\"/>";
        xmlQuery += "</Properties>";
        xmlQuery += "<Range><StartAt>" + startAt + "</StartAt><Count>" + count + "</Count></Range>";
        xmlQuery += "<EnableStemming>" + (enableStemming ? "true" : "false") + "</EnableStemming>";
        xmlQuery += "<TrimDuplicates>" + (trimDuplicates ? "true" : "false") + "</TrimDuplicates>";
        xmlQuery += "<IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>" + (ignoreAllNoiseQuery ? "true" : "false") + "</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>";
        xmlQuery += "<ImplicitAndBehavior>" + (impliciteAndBehavior ? "true" : "false") + "</ImplicitAndBehavior>";
        xmlQuery += "<IncludeRelevanceResults>" + (includeRelevanceResults ? "true" : "false") + "</IncludeRelevanceResults>";
        xmlQuery += "<IncludeSpecialTermResults>" + (includeSpecialTermResults ? "true" : "false") + "</IncludeSpecialTermResults>";
        xmlQuery += "<IncludeHighConfidenceResults>" + (includeHighConfidenceResults ? "true" : "false") + "</IncludeHighConfidenceResults>";
        xmlQuery += "</Query>";
        xmlQuery += "</QueryPacket>";
```

It returns some results, but the results come from all over the Sharepoint, not only from the site where I do my search. Is there any way to limit the scope of the search request to have only results from the site ?

Sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: Rather than use the Search.asmx you should use REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using REST with SharePoint online. The end point is formatted like this:

```
[site]/_api/search/query?querytext='query'
```

It is far easier to use and requests can be made from many platforms.

The documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx

You can either create a Result Source and use the SourceId attribute or you can just add the path to your query. (I prefer the result source myself.)